# Simplest possible regex to match date string

Tags: regex

What would be the simplest possible regex to match the following date format:

```
mm-dd-yy
```

i.e. 01-01-13

Comment: [This article](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html) may help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends, if you only want to match numbers:

```
\d\d-\d\d-\d\d
```

But if you want to be sure that any date is valid, it should be either imprecise or impossible (can't handle february).

Here is a better regex, but still not perfect:

```
(1[0-2]|0\d)-([0-2]\d|3[0-1])-\d\d
```

Comment: dude in mm 0-3 should be used

Answer (score 2):

I always use `\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}`, but note that this allows "dates" like `13-13-13`.

Writing a complete regex that will only match valid dates is so complicated that it is hardly worth the effort.

Another note is that this format is very ambiguous. If possible, use `yyyy-mm-dd` or `dd-mm-yyyy`.

Comment: are you sure `-` is not matched for range evaluation?

Comment: @Aniket: Only in a character class.

Comment: Yes. You'd have to use brackets to activate the range stuff, like ``[a-z]``.

Comment: ah cool .. thank you @minitech and mzedeler. I am a regex noob.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple :

```
 /^\d\d-\d\d-\d\d$/
```

But you should check that the date is valid using a date library after this simple format check : no reasonable regex will check you're not the 29 of february on a non bissextile year.

Answer (score 0):

```
/[1-3]{1,2}-[1-9]{1,2}-[1-9]{1,2}/
```

Comment: Which makes ``1-1-1`` a valid date format. I wouldn't really like it.

Comment: @mzedeler but that reads 1st jan 1st day 1st year i to agree this is not that much robust to check dates

Comment: Yes, but @Marty Wallace is asking for a two-digit format with leading zeroes.

Comment: @mzedeler ok then use /[1-3]{2}-[1-9]{2}-[1-9]{2}/

Comment: I can't see how that is going to match something like ``05-06-13``? (Or ``11-01-00`` for that matter.)

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here's one which matches only valid dates. Since you're using two-digit years, it assumes `00` is 2000 (which is a leap year); if you're looking for 1900 or 2100, it will require modification.

```
/^((0[13-9]|1[012])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)|([13578]|1[02])-31)-\d\d|02-(0[1-9]|[12][0-8])-\d\d|02-29-([02468][048]|[13579][26])$/
```